# It is necessary to calculate explicitly a chart $(U,\varphi)$ in order to obtain the Gaussian Curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, submanifold

I have the regular surface given by the zeros of $$f: \mathbb{R}^3\longrightarrow \mathbb{R} 
$$
$$ f(x) = (4x-2y-z)^2-1$$
I'm supposed to calculate the Gaussian Curvature of this surface, defined as $K=k_1k_2$ being $k_1$ and $k_2$ the principal curvatures.

To calculate the principal curvatures, I need the derivative of the Normal Unit Vector along the surface $\mathcal{N}$. In other words, I need a chart $(U,\varphi)$ of the surface so that I can calculate $\mathcal{N}$.

The only way I have of calculating a chart for $f$ is trying to view it as the graph of a function, hence I should try to obtain an expression for either $x$, $y$ or $z$ from the expression of $f$.
This is not possible as the expression is difficult to manipulate and it really doesn't seem to be the way.

Then how am I supposed to calculate the Gaussian Curvature? Is there any other method not involving an expression of a chart $(U,\varphi)$? I understand that for most $f$ is not easy to find an explicit chart.

Comment: Have you thought about the shape of this surface...? That settles the question without calculation.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang How am I supposed to find about its shape? It doesn't seem to be any (for me) known surface, such as a paraboloid or an hyperboloid. When I operate the terms of $f$ I just end up with a bunch of terms that are not any familiar shape as well: $16x^2+4y^2+z^2-16xy-8xz+4zy = 1$

Comment: Think simpler: What might a high-school algebra student do with $(4x - 2y - z)^{2} - 1 = 0$? :)

Comment: If you have to solve $u^2 - v^2 = 0$, always factor it and set each factor to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The zero set of your function is given by:

$$S = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \ \vert \ |4x - 2y-z| = 1 \}$$

This is a regular surface whose connected components are clearly planes. Therefore the Gaussian curvature of $S$ vanishes everywhere, i.e $K_S \equiv 0$.